# PHP getting HTTP error 500

Tags: php, android

I want to retrieve data from the hosting but it returns me a HTTP error 500 when I tried to test my php.

This is my php code:

```
 /**
 * Getting all stock
 */
public function getstockdesc() {
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM stockdesc");
    return $result;
}
```

This is the for sync into android sqllite:

```
<?php

include_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$stockdesc = $db->getstockdesc();
$a = array();
$b = array();
if($stockdesc != false){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($stockdesc)){
        $b["stockdescId"] = $row["stockdescId"];
        $b["stockdesc"] = $row["stockdesc"];
        $b["itemCode"] = $row["itemCode"];
        array_push($a,$b);
    }
    echo json_encode($a);
         return $b;
}
    else{
         return false;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: What does 500 mean?

Comment: @greenapps 500 is a internal server error.... OP needs to view their logs.

Comment: I know what it means!

Comment: hmm i dunno how to fix right now  @.@

Comment: You made connection in db with mysqli and used mysql_fetch_array in your loop, may be this is the issue, sometime when disble error logs in server then php error getting 500

Comment: Where do you see that error? AND WHAT DOES IT MEAN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

HOLY MOLY, I got the answers right now thx.

Recently using:

> mysql_fetch_array()

Need to change to

> mysqli_fetch_array()

My bad not paying attention!

Thanks Nipun Tyagi for finding my typo :D!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to see the actual error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Place it in the beginning of the code ;)

Comment: This is not a solution for the problem. So no answer. You should have placed this as a comment.

Comment: No darling !! this is the solution!!
Asking how to solve a 500 error is something like: "What is the meaning of life?"